# Difference b/w installing ionic localy and globaly?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4

**Hey cool people**, I am using Ionic for development and now I want to go deeper and I remember past issue I faced related to version of cordova, packages, NPM, Ionic.

**Example :** I'm having number of project which is ionic v1, v2, v3, v4 and now if I start new project then It will be v5 so how can we manage multiple version in same machine and provide same support for all version.

So my question is.

```
1) What is the pro and cons if I install ionic locally for my project or global ?

2) If every thing we install locally for specific project like NPM and Ionic, It will cause issue while building and publishing app ?
```

Every answer will be appreciated

I wish this question/answer will clear lot of people concept and doubt.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing different between them.

**Global CLI**

Is is good practice to install Global CLI, you can access CLI from everywhere in your terminal

**Local CLI**

Every time you want to generate new project with a specific CLI (heroku, ionic , angular etc), first you need to install them inside your local directory. (you lose more time)

Comment: So can I run and build all version of Ionic project from latest installed global Ionic CLI, NPM CLI, CordovaCLI ?

Comment: Sometimes it maybe be depend on how cli work. Not all are same. If you want to manage versioning. I suggest you to use NVM - Node Version Managment
https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm